# Right hand column overlapping left

Tags: bug, comments, sidebar

See for example the comments on this thread.

[Return latest entry result providing there is a review or close entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722817/return-latest-entry-result-providing-there-is-a-review-or-close-entry/38723970#comment64821981_38722817)

The comments are partially concealed beneath the text on the right hand side.

Image from Firefox 47.0.1
[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you're seeing. Nothing on that thread looks wrong to me. Could you add a screenshot to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Screenshot?  I do not see what you are talking about.

Comment: Scroll up. [This comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722817/return-latest-entry-result-providing-there-is-a-review-or-close-entry/38723970#comment64821981_38722817) seems to be the problem.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi What's wrong with it? I did look at the entire page, but other than the choice to strike it out vs. delete it, it looks fine to me.

Comment: @TZHX, on my browser (Firefox 47.0.1) the stroked-out comment does not break lines and runs beneath the right sidebar, impacting the comments below it.

Comment: I would say the left hand column is overlapping the right

Comment: @Sayse The glass is half full.

Comment: Looks like the commenter is using a Unicode feature to strikethrough text. Maybe Firefox doesn't like that?

Comment: Ah; blame diacritics / zalgo text then I guess.